# Looking for a website with the 1984 NIV Bible version

Tags: bible, resource-request, applications, niv

All the Bible websites that I know of have updated their NIV Bibles to the 2011 version. I used to use [biblestudytools.com](http://www.biblestudytools.com/) to access the 1984 version, but it now looks like it also has been updated to the 2011 version.

Can anyone point me to a site that still hosts the 1984 version? Or perhaps an eBook or other electronic means of accessing it? Whether free or for a price.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Reference request questions are somewhat iffy here, but we'll see if you get some responses. For more on what this site is about, please see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Meanwhile, I hope you'll browse some of the other questions and answers here.

Comment: "Reference request questions are somewhat iffy here" - only if they lack the specificity to avoid "primarily-opinion-based".  This is a good question - it is quite specific and is actually a resource request not a reference request.

Comment: @bruisedreed Good points.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This appears to be what you are after here:

http://biblemegasite.com/outline-niv1984.html

As well as click through links (by book and then section) through to the NIV 1984 version hosted at [studylight.org](http://www.studylight.org/), it has  [links](http://www.biblewebapp.com/niv2011-changes/) [that compare the changes](http://www.slowley.com/niv2011_comparison/) [in the newer version](https://www.biblegateway.com/niv/Translators-Notes.pdf), and even a link to [an audio version](http://www.bible.is/EN1NIV/Matt/1) hosted at [bible.is](http://www.bible.is/); although what [Zondervan](http://www.zondervan.com/) would have to say about some of their links I don't know...

Comment: [StudyLight.org](http://classic.studylight.org/) is exactly what I was looking for, but I'm also glad for the pdf links in BibleMegasite as a backup.

Comment: Studylight and Bible.is are still good sources at the moment (July 2018). If they ever change to the 2011 version, Biblemegasite will probably find other links if they can.

Answer (score 3):

For iOS, I can personally recommend the [Spectrum Bible](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/wave-parallel-bible/id336014635) (formerly "WAVE Parallel Bible"), which has the (1984) NIV available as a purchasable add-on. (You can preview before purchasing so you can be sure it's the right one.)

It has a refreshing visual style, is ad-free, and comes with a wide spectrum of free translations: KJV, Amplified, NASB, NET, and God's Word. Many others, including NIV, ESV and original Greek/Hebrew, can be purchased.

Once purchased, translations are available for offline use.

[image: WAVE Parallel Bible (Portrait)]

[image: Spectrum Bible (Landscape)]

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for physical copies of 1984 NIV, the Christian Bookshop in Milton Keynes specialises in them - both new and used copies. You can find them at mkcb.org

Comment: The question specifically asks for an "electronic means of accessing" the 1984 NIV.